# iOS 6 navigation bar not centering correctly

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have a problem with my navigation bar. I'm setting a custom font, and the centering is not right, the back button it's moving everything to the right.

```
UILabel *navLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 300, 100)];
navLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
navLabel.text = dataFromOtherView.text;
navLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
navLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:1.0];
navLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
navLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:22.0];
navLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.navigationItem.titleView = navLabel;
```

[image]

Comment: The documentation for the 'titleView' property states "This property is ignored if leftBarButtonItem is not nil."  Your leftBarButtonItem is not nil; perhaps something is being ignored?  If instead of setting titleView you just set the navigationItems title, then does the text no longer move right?

Comment: yes if I just set the navigation title, doesn't move... but then how can I use a custom font?

Comment: Actually, I think your leftBarButtonItem IS nil so it is not being ignored.  [The backButton is not your leftBarButtonItem.]  See possible answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the label is so large that there is not enough 'open/flexible space' between the left side of the label and the right side of the back button.  Try reducing the width of UILabel when you create it.